# Power series substitution endomorphisms: corollary $7.17$ in Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra

It the corollary $7.17$ in the commutative algebra book of David Eisenbud, as follows:
[image]

I could not understand the highlighted line.

What does mean by the line $\text{image of $\varphi(x)=f$ of the generator $X$ of ${\color{blue}{(x)}}$ of ${\color{red}{(x)}}$}$ ?

I understand that the ideal ${\color{blue}{(x)}}$ from the domain ring $R[[x]]$ and the ideal ${\color{red}{(x)}}$ is from the co-domain ring $R[[x]]$.

But why $X$ is used here instead of $x$ ?

The image of the generator $X$ should be $\varphi(X)=f$ instead of $\varphi(x)=f$.

Can you explain please ?

Comment: I believe this is a typo - $X$ ought to be $x$.

Comment: @NathanLowry, I also think that but not sure